# How To Play Youtube Videos In WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, youtube

Are there any good .net libraries / controls for playing youtube videos in a WPF application?  I know I could use the WebBrowser control but wouldn't that display the whole page and not just the video?  A control where I only have to supply a youtube URL would be best.

Comment: If you use the embed url it would work just fine with the WebBrowser. The entire webpage would just show the video.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this. The project is about creating Drag/Dropable items in WPF, but you can see that there's a video playing in one of the controls. You should be able to extract what you need from that.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part